# Does category-encoders have some randomness built-in to it?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, category-encoders

I used the [category-encoders](https://pypi.org/project/category-encoders/) package to target encode some variables. However upon multiple runs it seems there are some tiny differences between the encodings. I haven't had time to dig deeper into it, but suspect there is some randomness in how the encoding is done. Is this correct? If so, can a random seed be set to get deterministic results, or do we need a PR in the repo?

Comment: Can you give a minimal reproducible example? You mean the `TargetEncoder` class, I assume?

Comment: @BenReiniger would love to but it's on a proprietary dataset I can't share, so it'll take significant time to generate an example. Maybe in some weeks I can get to it

Answer (score 1):

I've looked into the source code for the [`target_encoder`](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/_modules/category_encoders/target_encoder.html#TargetEncoder) within the `category-encoders` package, and I haven't found any areas where randomness or non-determinism would come into play in the encoding process itself.

To further confirm this, I conducted a series of tests where I applied target-encoding to various datasets multiple times. For each iteration and each dataset, the encodings provided by the package were identical, which indicates deterministic behavior.

Given these findings, I suspect that the non-determinism you're experiencing might not originate from the `category-encoders` package itself, but rather from other parts of your data processing pipeline.

Comment: It must be from the data I'm working with. Thanks.